# Running only my application with full trust in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Is there a way that my clients can run just my application in full trust and not any other ones?

I don't want some weird virus application to be given full trust alone with my own.

Can this be set by application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the trust level of your own application but you can't play in other application's backyard.

To me, what you are trying to do is an overkill anyway.

There's zillions of virus out there and I'm almost sure none of them are written in Silverlight.  Dealing with virus on your client's machines is not your responsability.  Your responsability is to protect the server from any kind of attack.

Answer (score 1):

Elevated trust for OOB (Out of browser) Silverlight applications is set on a per-application basis.
[image]